# Generic taxonomy-term template page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, terms

because of my taxonomy hierarchy, my taxonomy-type.php template is already used, is there a way to have only one taxonomy-type-term.php template ?

I've got 13 sub terms, do I need to create 13 taxonomy-type-[term].php templates ?

Thanks.

Cyril

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you're trying to accomplish? What, for instance, do you want different on each of the subterms? I built a template recently where I setup several conditionals to handle the main term and then the subterms, all in the same taxonomy template. That may work for you.

Comment: Yes, I think it can do the trick, can you please share the code of this template with me ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`.

Refer to the [Template Hierarchy Codex entry regarding taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display).

WordPress will look for taxonomy template files in the following order:

1. `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` - If the taxonomy were `sometax`, and taxonomy's slug were `someterm` WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php`.
2. **`taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` - If the taxonomy were `sometax`, WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax.php`**
3. `taxonomy.php`
4. `archive.php`
5. `index.php`

**EDIT**

If you're already using `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` for something *other than* the index archive for `{taxonomy}`, perhaps you should re-consider your current use of this template file?

Comment: Actually, my taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php is already use.

Comment: What is `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` in use as, already, if not as the generic index archive template for `{taxonomy}`?